# create a keybind to jump directly to a specific gnus mailbox summary view?

Tags: key-bindings, gnus

I want to be able to jump directly via a keybind to a specific mailbox summary view in gnus.

for example in the groups view i have a mailbox

`*        0: nnimap+zeltak:INBOX`

i want to be able to jumo directly to the summary view of the above bookmark. anyone know if thats possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this (put it into your `.gnus.el`):

```
(defun goto-group-XXX ()
  "Jump to group XXX."
  (interactive)
  (gnus-group-jump-to-group "XXX")
  (gnus-group-select-group))

(define-key gnus-group-mode-map (kbd "v j")
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (goto-group-XXX)))
```

Replace the `XXX` by the group name (`nnimap+zeltak:INBOX`)
Also have a look at the `gnus-group-quick-select-group` function.

Comment: thx, its perfect!